# get php syntax error each time trying to use mysql statement

Tags: php

I have a while statement like this:

```
while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){      

  $comments .= "<fieldset> User Says : <div class='each_comment'>  <small><em> ".convert($row['comment_date'])." </em></small><br />".$row['comment']." 

  <input type='text' class='reply' comments_id='{$row['comments_id']}' />

      </div></fieldset>  </br>"; 
}
```

all I want to do is to insert this line:

```
 $reply_query = mysql_query("SELECT reply_id, reply FROM comments_reply WHERE comments_id='$comments_id' ");
```

above input and under $comments. The problem is that whatever I have tried causes me error. This is how I did it so far:

```
while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){      

  $comments .= "<fieldset> User Says : <div class='each_comment'>  <small><em> ".convert($row['comment_date'])." </em></small><br />".$row['comment']." 

      $reply_query = mysql_query("SELECT reply_id, reply FROM comments_reply WHERE comments_id='$comments_id' ");

  <input type='text' class='reply' comments_id='{$row['comments_id']}' />

      </div></fieldset>  </br>"; 
}
```

is it possible to use it there? Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Not embedded in the actual html markup.... the colouring here should give you a clue that your quotes aren't being closed properly, as would a syntax-highlighting editor or IDE

Comment: so I cannot use it here?

Comment: You have to separate your query from the markup that you're building

Comment: any idea how to do this? any example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $comments .= "<fieldset> User Says : <div class='each_comment'>  <small><em> ".convert($row['comment_date'])." </em></small><br />".$row['comment'];
    $reply_query = mysql_query("SELECT reply_id, reply FROM comments_reply WHERE comments_id='$comments_id' ");
    while ($row2= mysql_fetch_assoc($reply_query)) {
        // do what you want with the reply results
    }
    $comments .= "<input type='text' class='reply' comments_id='{$row['comments_id']}' />
    </div></fieldset>  </br>"; 
}
```

Comment: thank so much friend. This is what I was looking for. You saved me a lot of time!